# How to make extender plugs neat?

Tags: substitute-tool, efficiency, electricity

At place like desk or near bad, usually lots of power plug from electronics charging, fan, lamps, laptops, like from three to ten. Using extender plug is required, but messy. Is there any way to make it neat?

Comment: This is a shopping item. One term for it is a "cable tidy." One thing I do for wires that don't get moved is use plastic ties.

Comment: And for cables that do get moved, use Velcro cable ties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With my desk, I recently "rewired" it by screwing extension leads to the underside of the desk so that all of the equipment can be plugged into a socket which is very nearby and is out of sight.

I used cable clips and other methods to secure all of the wires to the underside of the desk also.

In some cases, I cut the length of the power cord so it was no longer than necessary. This is obviously a drastic measure which might give you a problem if you decide to move the device afterwards. It is easier to do if the device is a printer which uses a standard "figure-8" cable, because you can always buy a new one if necessary. The same applies to  monitors with "kettle" leads.

If you can't cut the leads then fold up any excess and use a cable-tie to hold the bundle together.

I also bought little racks which screw to the underside of the desk and these bundles of wire (and power supply boxes) all sit in those little racks, off the floor, off the desk and out of sight.